# How to add a files to a zipped file but to it's subfolders with command prompt?

Tags: file, command, zip, directory

Trying to add .xml files to an existing ZIP file which was subfolders, but cannot see to add them i.e. to \ETC, instead it adds it to the root zip level, also just to clarify I am using the command:

```
Winrar a -u ZippedFile.zip fileToUpdate.xml
```

Comment: You're missing some important information.  For example, "I am using the command."  You're using the WHAT command?

Comment: Sorry you are correct, I meant the COMMAND LINE in WINRAR to make it work :-)

Comment: Syntax I am using: Winrar a -u ZippedFile.zip fileToUpdate.xml

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are trying to run this from the command-line and not the GUI, you should use rar instead of Winrar, since Winrar starts the WinRaR GUI.

Your command, `a -u ZippedFile.zip fileToUpdate.xml`, assumes a single file to update that's located in same directory as the archive. That's why it doesn't get updated to the ETC folder, even though it may be located there. One way to get this to work like you want is to include the path of the file(s) in the command like so: `rar a -u ZippedFile.zip "C:\ETC\*.xml"`(for multiple .xml files). This will work regardless of where the archive is located.

If the archive must stay in the same directory as the XML files, you can use this command to specify that updated files are to be placed in the ETC folder within the archive, `rar a -u -apETC ZippedFile.zip fileToUpdate.xml` (single .xml file) or `rar a -u -apETC ZippedFile.zip *.xml`(multiple .xml files).